# Отправка запросов на сервер с интервалом

Tags: android

Необходимо отравлять запросы на сервер с целью узнать изменения данных в БД.

Сервер предоставляет API которое позволяет определить нужно ли подтягивать новые данные или нет. Вот только со стороны приложения я не пойму как это организовать...выделять по это отдельный фоновый поток и запихнуть его в while который будет выполнятся постоянно?

Comment: Не совсем так. Вечный цикл в потоке. И не `while` а лучше `for(;;)`

Comment: пардон, именно так и имел ввиду, цикл в поток. Просто я думал есть какие-то другие решения это задачи, ибо делать цикл подобный это как-то не особо красиво

Comment: Почему же? Вы хотите что-то делать через определённый промежуток времени. Заводитк поток с циклом и засыпаниями и все.

Comment: Сделайте лучше через push уведомление с сервера. Сервер прислал пуш, клиент делает запрос на сервер

Answer (score 3):

Со стороны приложения, вам необходимо реализовать AlarmManager, который будет просыпаться, будить приложение, выполнять задачу, ставить новое время для пробуждения и опять засыпать.

Если вы сделаете всё в цикле, то приложение не сможет спать, а, значит, будет огромное энергопотребление и система будет очень ругаться.

Вы можете сделать два вида Алармов.
Первый - работает только когда приложение не спит. Вот пример

```
public class UpdateScheduler extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 3998;
    private static final int UPDATE_TIME = 60 * 1000 * 10; //10 minutes
    public static final String INTENT_TIME_UPDATE = "ваш.пакет.TIME_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //отменим все дублирующие вызовы расписания
        //этот же метод можно вызвать из любого места программы и выключить обновления
        cancelSchedule(context);

        update();

        //следующий запуск
        nextSchedule(context);
    }

    private void update() {
        //todo тут ваш метод обновления
    }

    private void nextSchedule(Context context) {
        PendingIntent operation = getOperationIntent(context);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(operation);

        Calendar calUpdater = Calendar.getInstance();
        calUpdater.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, UPDATE_TIME);

        //Намерение будет послано через UPDATE_TIME миллисекунд
        //Для разных версий Андроида свой метод
        final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
        }
        else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
        }
        else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(),
                    operation);
        }
    }


    public static void cancelSchedule(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(getOperationIntent(context));
    }


    private static PendingIntent getOperationIntent(Context context) {
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(INTENT_TIME_UPDATE), 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    }
}
```

В том случае, если вы хотите, чтобы обновления работало, даже когда приложение спит, то нужно наследоваться от WakefulBroadcastReceiver и код будет примерно вот такой

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String INTENT_ALARM_UPDATE = "ваш.пакет.ALARM_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        update();

        // Next alarm
        schedule(context);
    }

    private void update() {
        //todo тут ваш метод обновления
    }

    public static void schedule(Context context) {
        Calendar calUpdater = Calendar.getInstance();
        calUpdater.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, TIME_UPDATE);

        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(INTENT_ALARM_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentAlarm,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            service.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pending);
        } else {
            service.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
        }

    }
}
```

Примечание: ресиверы обязательно прописать в манифесте

```
       <receiver android:name="ваш.пакет.UpdateScheduler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ваш.пакет.TIME_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!